# I am creating an application with expo go. It works flawlessly with the expo go application, but my apk output does not open and crashes immediately

Tags: expo-go

My application, which works perfectly with expo, does not open at all in my apk output. Expo doctor did not give any errors. I checked all my dependencies and they are all working properly. What could be the reason?

I checked all the dependencies, created a new project and transferred all the files there, but it didn’t help. It works with expo go, but my apk output doesn’t work.